# cannot upload image onto server without using UI thread

Tags: android

```
     public void upload_prescription()
{
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","Uploading file...", true);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    //     option1      upload_image.uploadFile(uploadFilePath);
                }
            }
            );
            //option2          upload_image.uploadFile(uploadFilePath);
            deleteImageFromGallery(delete_image_id + "");
        }
    }
    ).start();
}
```

Hey i tried  above code to upload image onto server.it runs well if i use the option 2 mentioned on the code. but if i put the code on the option 2.it gives me this error.

```
              android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
```

i think option 2 is better because it give a separate thread to complete the though it does not work properly

Comment: It doesn't work because you are (as your error has indicated) not spawning a new thread to do your network actions and instead are doing your network calls on the main thread. Your option2 just looks like normal method calls. I see no thread being spawned here.

Comment: what do you mean by normal method.

Comment: You're just calling a method on the UI thread. You aren't spawning a thread to do the work.

Comment: do you think my option 1 and option 2 run on ui thread

Comment: Calling runOnUiThread forces your operation to be run on the main thread. You can't use that to perform an upload. If you remove the runOnUiThread portion, your upload will run on a different thread.